# How can I tell if it's me or my computer hardware, that causes the ctrl keypress to not get noticed?

Tags: macos, emacs, keypress

I work in Emacs. For some months now, on my MacBook Pro, frequently when I type like Ctrl-`some character`, it doesn't recognize the Ctrl and the `some character` annoying is inserted into the buffer. I am trying to figure out if is me, my software, or my hardware. Any suggestions on how I can figure this out? Sometimes it happens with other meta keys. Maybe I just need to do hand-strengthening exercises? It's starting to eat into my productivity.

Comment: Are you asking in general, or are you asking how to know whether only Emacs does not see the key? If this isn't just about Emacs then maybe remove the `emacs` tag.

Comment: All I can suggest is installing some kind of key logger to your OS, and then when it happens check the log and see whether or not it registered a modifier for that key sequence.

Comment: You might also try using a different keyboard for a while.  I wouldn't think it's a matter of hand strength though -- IIRC Mac keyboards have virtually no travel at all (they've always looked *awful* to me), so if you think you're pressing a key I expect you really are.

Comment: FWIW it seems highly unlikely to me that Emacs is receiving a modified key sequence and then sometimes de-modifying it.

Comment: Lots of great suggestions from @phils. I will post , if I figure this out.

Comment: For all the years I've used emacs, I was unaware of open-dribble-file. I'm going to see if that helps.

Comment: on linux I would use `xev`, which it appears can work on macos as [well](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/351883/how-to-dump-raw-mouse-input-events)

Comment: So emacs dribble file tells me it didn't receive the keypress. Have to meditate about what that really tells me.

Comment: to run xev, it looks like I would need to run XQuartz. I hoping for something simpler.

Comment: Closing this.Found out in work Slack that hard-to-press keys on Mac is a real thing, so its off to the Genius Bar. Also, C-M-] was coming across as M-], so I consciously re-pressed with lots of pressure on ctrl  key. (unnatural pressure)

Answer (score 1):

Just install a tool like karabiner-elements, e. g. with HomeBrew:

```
brew cask install karabiner-elements
```

and start the

```
Karabiner-EventViewer.app
```

which shows all key presses you have been pressing down.